# How does strcasestr in C work. Keep getting Error external symbol

Tags: c

I have defined _GNU_SOURCE but when i try to put strcasestr in my function it just says error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strcasestr referenced in function. Do i need to import a specific library somehow or do something else? I have also tried defining:

```
//char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
#define _GNU_SOURCE        
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The way i use it

```
if ((strcasestr(str1,str2)) != NULL)
    {
      //code
    }
```

Any other way to compare strings without case sensitivity?

Comment: Can't reproduce on GCC Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcasestr` is a non standard function.  What library are you linking with your project?  If you use MingW in Windows, this function may not be available as your program is linked with the Microsoft C runtime library.

The same functionality may be available there under the name `stristr` or `_stristr`.

Otherwise, you may have to write your own version.

Here is a very simplistic one:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *strcasestr(const char *str, const char *pattern) {
    size_t i;
    unsigned char c0 = *pattern, c1, c2;

    if (c0 == '\0')
        return (char *)str;

    c0 = toupper(c0);
    for (; (c1 = *str) != '\0'; str++) {
        if (toupper(c1) == c0) {
            for (i = 1;; i++) {
                c2 = pattern[i];
                if (c2 != '\0')
                    return (char *)str;
                c1 = str[i];
                if (toupper(c1) != toupper(c2))
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: im just using standard Microsoft C library i assume since i have not changed anything.

Comment: @deathskiller: If you use Microsoft Visual Studio, then `strcasestr` is not available and defining `_GNU_SOURCE` does not change anything.

Comment: oh :/ is there anything i can do apart from writing my own version? because i cant seem to make my own version work

Comment: nvm i was able to make my own version work. thank you

Comment: @nvm: your version should also handle the border case where `needle` is the empty string. `strcasestr` must return the `haystack` in this case.

Comment: @chqrlie as I reused your code on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519761/mimetex-installation-on-windows-7 I also up-voted your answer.

Comment: @matzeri: thank you. I modified the code to ensure defined behavior for negative characters on platforms with signed char.

Comment: A bit late here, but this converts arguments to upper-case to perform the comparison, but both [POSIX `strcasecmp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html) and [Windows `stricmp()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stricmp-wcsicmp-mbsicmp-stricmp-l-wcsicmp-l-mbsicmp-l?view=msvc-170) convert their arguments to lower case.  That could cause inconsistent results under some locale settings - Turkish in particular comes to mind, with its `ı`/`i` and `I`/`İ`.  And likely others.

Answer (score 5):

Can you just use:

```
#include <shlwapi.h>
...
#define strcasestr StrStrIA
```

From microsoft's crazy documentation pages:

"StrStrIA function:

Finds the first occurrence of a substring within a string. The comparison is not case-sensitive."

```
PCSTR StrStrIA(
  PCSTR pszFirst,
  PCSTR pszSrch
);
```

Where:

"Parameters:

pszFirst Type: PTSTR

A pointer to the null-terminated string being searched.

pszSrch Type: PCTSTR

A pointer to the substring to search for."

Remember to add shlawpi.lib to your project settings else it's not going to link.